# Wordpress - how does one suggest a page template that a link should use?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

So my archives page uses two WP functions, wp_get_archives and wp_list_categories.

When I click one of the links provided by 'wp_get_archives' I am taken to the index (bad), but links issued by 'wp_list_categories' go (correctly) to my 'cat' page.

```
    <h3>Archives by Month:</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h3>Archives by Subject:</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>
```

How do I make archive links open in certain page templates?

Many Thanks,

Simon.

Answer (score 0):

For date archives you can use `date.php` template.
This is the hierarchy for category:
`category-$slug.php --> category-$id.php --> category.php --> archive.php --> index.php`

This is the hierarchy for date archives:
`date.php --> archive.php --> index.php`

If you want same template for category and date archive pages then you can use `archive.php`

You can find the detail documentation here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/